# Storm cannot find class

Tags: maven, apache-storm

I found this error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class storm.starter.WordCountTopology
```

when i wrote this command

```
user@ubuntu:~/Storm/storm$ bin/storm jar storm-starter.jar storm.starter.WordCountTopology
```

what's wrong of this ...?

i want to know what's the difference between mvn command like `mvn -f m2-pom.xml` and `storm jar` ? are both of them submit topology ?

I want to know the storm jar command in details as i put storm-starter .jar in bin of storm

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: Could not find or load main class storm.starter.WordCountTopology

This means that this class is not available in the `storm-starter.jar`. Search for `executable jar` here at SO to find a solution.

> i want to know what's the difference between mvn command like mvn -f m2-pom.xml and storm jar ? are both of them submit topology ?

Normally `mvn -f m2-pom.xml` won't do very much, unless there's a default goal/phase specified in the `pom.xml`. Maven is used to compile the sourcefiles and package them as a jar. `java -jar ...` is used to execute this jarfile.